# std::end with raw arrays of char

Tags: c++, c++11

By default, the `std::end` overload for raw arrays looks something like this:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
T* end(T (&array)[N])
{ return array + N; }
```

However, this overload was undesirable for me when passing a string literal or a `char` array, as they both have an implicit `\0` at the end which gets counted.

I thought as a workaround I could overload `end` in my own namespace:

**Example**:

```
namespace unique
{
    const char* end(const char (&array)[5])
    {
        return array + 4;
    }
    const char* end(const char (&array)[11])
    {
        return array + 10;
    }
}

int main()
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    using unique::end;
    const char str1[] = "XXXTEXTXXX";
    const char str2[] = "TEXT";
    auto iter = std::search(begin(str1), end(str1), begin(str2), end(str2));
    //...
}
```

However, that would require a lot of overloads to write.

**QUESTION**

I realize using `std::string` or another container would solve my problem. However, I wanted to be able to call `end` unqualified with a string literal or raw array and have it omit the null terminator as above. Is there a better approach that would avoid writing the overloads?

Comment: To avoid writing overloads you just use the template method and in the implementation subtract one for `N`. But this really shouldn't be named `end`, but `string_end` or something. The fact of the matter is that C-strings are a convention, and the end of an array doesn't change because of that. The end of a literal truly does include the terminator. That's why it should have a different name.

Comment: You visibly want the end of the string instead of the end of the array, and it now becomes a question of what's an acceptable "end of string" iterator to return. The easy heuristic (return `array + N - 1`) does not work if there's a null character in the middle of your `char` array or if the array is not null-terminated. If that does not worry you, I don't see why you aren't using that heuristic already. If it does worry you, your `end` function will probably need to run in linear time instead of constant time.

Comment: @GManNickG: Originally, I just wanted to call `end` regardless of the type, but I agree with your point and probably will change the name. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious (if you're sure it'll only be used under the right circumstances) would be a variant of the original:

```
namespace unique {
template<class T, std::size_t N>
T* end(T (&array)[N])
{ return array + N-1; }
}
```

Just be sure to only use it in the right situations, or you'll end up with `end` that points one before the end.

If you want to restrict it to character types, you can use a couple of overloads that only work for character types:

```
namespace unique {
    template <std::size_t N>
    char *end(char (&array)[N])
    {
        return array + N - 1;
    }

    template <std::size_t N>
    wchar_t *end(wchar_t (&array)[N])
    {
        return array + N - 1;
    }
}
```

With this, an array of `char` will use the version that assumes a NUL terminator, but an array of `int` will use `std::end` so it refers to the entire array:

```
int main()
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    using unique::end;
    char str1 [] = "12345";
    wchar_t str2 [] = L"12345";
    int i4 [] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    std::cout << std::distance(begin(str1), end(str1)) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::distance(begin(str2), end(str2)) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::distance(begin(i4), end(i4)) << "\n";
}
```

Do note, however, that since there's an existing template named `begin`, these overloads will only match exact types, so if you want them to work with `const char` and `const wchar_t` (for example) those will require separate overloads from the ones above that work with non-const types.

Also note that these will still apply to `typedef`s, so (for example) the fairly common:

```
typedef char small_int;
```

...can/will lead to problems -- the real type is still char, so `end(my_small_int_array)` will use the `char` overload instead of the base template.

Comment: Waiting on @GmanNickG to enlighten my over-tired mind on what's wrong with this idea...

Comment: Oh doh, although I would only want that behavior with strings.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Heh. :) For the reasons I put in my comment on the question: I don't feel right writing something called `end` that can be called with the exact same arguments as `std::end`, yet returns a different value. Too much potential for confusion and nothing strongly differentiates them at the callsite. I would name it `string_end` or similar, but if I did that I wouldn't really be answering the question, so it went into a comment.

Comment: @GManNickG: Okay -- I think I gave fair warning about that (and, in fairness, by putting them in a namespace, you're at least *helping* ensure they'll only be used when desired).

Comment: @JesseGood: see revised version in edited answer. Could probably use a template for all character types with some clever use of `enable_if`, but I'm afraid I'm too tired to even try that right now.